# Detect Login in Owin for updating Database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin, katana

I am using Owin for authentication in my ASP.net MVC application:

```
app.UseApplicationSignInCookie();
app.UseFormsAuthentication(new FormsAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
    ExpireTimeSpan = 64800 /* cookie valid for 48 Days */
});
```

In my database I store the users last login date and I use this to send mails to inactive users. If the user manually does a login on my site, I can easily update the database. But if the user has the 'remember me' Cookie set, Owin automatically re-authenticates the user and I never get signaled that this user did just start a new session.

Is there some sort of event which Owin fires as soon it has successfully authenticated a user in any way? I would expect something like that sample:

```
app.OnUserAuthenticated += () => {
    var user = HttpContext.Current.User;
    /* hooray i am authenticated */
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm not into OWIN yet I will suggest something else. You could hook up some code on the Session_Start event and check if the user is authenticated there. If the user is authenticated you can go ahead and update the information in your DB.

Comment: Session != authentication. I wouldn't suggest binding the 2 together

Comment: I understand that, but at the time a user session starts it's a good place to find out if he is authenticated and update the desired table in the database. Since a user will most likely will have one session open at a time there won't be as much updates firing.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of just checking if a new session with a HttpContext.Current.User set. Basically a new session with a user is the same as a new login. Owin already ensures that the user is set before Session_Start.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put middleware after the cookie middleware that looks for OwinContext.Authentication.User != null? This would basically do the same as the event you're looking for.

Comment: I just tried to implement this but actually this won't work. After the cookie middleware the user will always be authenticated. I can't detect if the user was authenticated during this cookie middleware.